# Use batch to redirect prints into a file

Tags: python, batch-file, logging, cmd

I want to run a python file and have all the prints redirect into a txt file.
**note the files are in the same folder.**
I used this command in a batch file:

```
code.py > log.txt
```

I also tried:

```
C:/mypath/code.py > log.txt
START /B C:/mypath/code.py > log.txt
START /B C:/mypath/code.py > C:/mypath/log.txt
START /B C:/mypath/code.py > C:/mypath/log.txt
```

All of these run the python script and created a log file but didn't save anything in the file.

EDIT:
people wanted to see the code so here it is: (There are some pictures and other assets so here's a google drive with all the files) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rbUfoQ79CiC-DHViRXx89z8IaY1MIqlP?usp=sharing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#dvd screensaver that runs when the computer is idle for a certain amount of time

from ctypes import Structure, windll, c_uint, sizeof, byref #afktime imports

#behind the scenes imports
from random import randint
import time
from datetime import datetime
import ctypes
import sys
#behind the scenes imports

import pygame #visual imports

# Settings
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
SIZE1 = user32.GetSystemMetrics(78), user32.GetSystemMetrics(79)
SIZE = width, height = SIZE1
BG_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)  
fullscreen = True 
AFK_threshold = 10 #seconds
color = 1
round_afk = 0
last_print = 0
now = datetime.now()
exit = False
seconds_in_day = 60 * 60 * 24
seconds_in_hour = 60 * 60
seconds_in_minute = 60
start = True
#settings

#afktime
class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure): #class for afktime
    _fields_ = [ 
        ('cbSize', c_uint), #set the size of the struct
        ('dwTime', c_uint), #set the time
    ]

def get_idle_duration(): #function for afktime
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO() #create a struct
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo) #set the size of the struct
    windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo)) #get the time
    millis = windll.kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime #get the time
    return millis / 1000.0 #return the time in seconds
#adktime

#main loop
while True:
    sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w") #log file

    if start == True: #start screen
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") #current date and time
        print("program started " + dt_string) #print program start time and date
        print(" ") #print a empty line

    round_afk = round(get_idle_duration()) #round afktime
    if round_afk != last_print: #if last printed number is not the same as the current afktime
        print(round_afk) #print afktime rounded to the nearest second
        last_print = round_afk #set last printed number to the current afktime
    
    if get_idle_duration() >= AFK_threshold: #if afktime is greater than threshold
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") #get current time and date
        start = time.time() #start the timer
        print(" ") #print a empty line
        print("your are afk ", dt_string) #print afktime and current time and date
        print(" ") #print a empty line
        
        #visual portion
        logo = pygame.image.load("assets/logo_color/logo{}.png".format(color)) #load dvd logo
        logo = pygame.transform.scale(logo, (100, 50)) #resize dvd logo
        clock = pygame.time.Clock() #create clock
        img_size = logo.get_rect().size #get dvd logo size
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE) #set screen size
        pygame.display.set_caption('DVD Corner') #set caption

        if fullscreen: #if fullscreen
            DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN) #set fullscreen
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False) #hide mouse


        x = randint(50, width-60) #random x position
        y = randint(50, height-60) #random y position
        x_speed = 2.5 #x speed
        y_speed = 2.5 #y speed


        def move(x, y): #function for moving dvd logo
            screen.blit(logo, (x, y)) #blit dvd logo


        while exit == False: #while exit is false
            screen.fill(BG_COLOR) #fill screen with background color
            if (x + img_size[0] >= width) or (x <= 0): #change color if dvd logo hits the edge of the screen
                if color == 8: #if color is 8
                    color = 1 #set color to 1
                else: #if color is not 8
                    color += 1 #add 1 to color
                logo = pygame.image.load("assets/logo_color/logo{}.png".format(color)) #load dvd logo after color change
                logo = pygame.transform.scale(logo, (100, 50)) #resize dvd logo
                img_size = logo.get_rect().size #get dvd logo size
                x_speed = -x_speed #change x speed

            if (y + img_size[1] >= height) or (y <= 0): #change color if dvd logo hits the edge of the screen
                if color == 8: #if color is 8
                    color = 1 #set color to 1
                else: #if color is not 8
                    color += 1 #add 1 to color
                logo = pygame.image.load("assets/logo_color/logo{}.png".format(color)) #load dvd logo after color change
                logo = pygame.transform.scale(logo, (100, 50)) #resize dvd logo
                img_size = logo.get_rect().size #get dvd logo size
                y_speed = -y_speed #change y speed

            if (y + img_size[1] >= height) and (x + img_size[0] >= width): #check if dvd hit the corner
                print("corner") #print corner

            #move dvd logo
            x += x_speed 
            y += y_speed 
            move(x, y) 
            #move dvd logo

            pygame.display.update() #update the display
            clock.tick(60) 

            for event in pygame.event.get(): #if evet exit exit
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                    exit = True

            if get_idle_duration() <= AFK_threshold: #if idle duration is smaller then threshhold exit
                pygame.quit()
                break
        
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") #get current time and date
        end = time.time() #end the timer
        gap = end - start #gap between start and end
        gap_round = round(gap) #round gap

        days = gap_round // seconds_in_day #get days
        hours = (gap_round - (days * seconds_in_day)) // seconds_in_hour #get hours
        minutes = (gap_round - (days * seconds_in_day) - (hours * seconds_in_hour)) // seconds_in_minute #get minutes
        gap = str(days) + " days, " + str(hours) + " hours, " + str(minutes) + " minutes and " + str(gap_round) + " seconds" #create gap string

        print(" ") #print blank line
        print("you are no longer idle " + dt_string) #print you are no longer idle and current time and date and for how long
        print("total time idle: ", gap) #print total time idle
        print(" ") #print blank line

        sys.stdout.close()
        pygame.quit() #exit
        #visual portion


#main loop
```

The code is a screensaver app that after a certain amount of time opens the screensaver.

Comment: It works for sure. The problem is that your script doesn't write anything to stdout. You can make script with single line `print('test')` and launch it using cmd line `python script.py > log.txt`

Comment: It will not work with `start /B` since it does *not* wait until `code.py` is done, so the log file is going to become closed before the Python script writes anything out…

Comment: If you add a `/wait` option to the `START` command, it ***will*** wait until the python script has finished.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 ways to do it:

1. in `cmd` -> `python script.py > log.txt`
2. in your python code:

example:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(PATH_TO_LOG_FILE, "w")
print("hello world")
sys.stdout.close()
```

output: `hello world` (in log text file)

Comment: the idea you suggested worked with a file only with the code you wrote but with the regular code, it didn't work. the code is too long for a comment so I added it to the main question.